# How to call a synchronous sub function from a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, synchronous

I'd like to run all of my functions synchronously.  But if I execute something like the code below the response is sent back before the return value is assigned.

index.js

```
exports.cfTest = (req, res) => {
    try {
        result = columnCount(
         'project','dataset','table'
        );
        console.log('sending response');
        res.send('<OUTPUT>' + result + '</OUTPUT>');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send('<ERROR>' + err + '</ERROR>');     
    }
};

function columnCount(projectId, bqDataset, bqTable) {

    const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
    const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId: projectId});

    var result;

    bigquery
    .dataset(bqDataset)
    .table(bqTable)
    .get()
    .then(results => {
        result = results[1].schema.fields.length;   
    })
    .catch(err => {
        result = null;
    });

    console.log('returning ' + result);
    return result;
}
```

I.e the console output would be something like:

```
<OUTPUT>undefined</OUTPUT>
```

and in the Stackdriver logs would show an execution order like this:

```
 2018-07-25 10:00:00 - Function execution started
 2018-07-25 10:00:01 - sending response
 2018-07-25 10:00:02 - Function execution took 2000 ms, finished with status code: 200
 2018-07-25 10:00:03 - returning 5
```

This is any elegant way to lock down execution into synchronous only behaviour?

**Solution**

The async/await approach suggested below by Alexandru works!  Thanks Alexandru.

NB: *But* not with standard/GA Cloud Functions.  You'll have to use the [Google Cloud Functions Node.js v8 Beta](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is you can look at `async/await`

Your code will look something like this one in the end:

```
async function columnCount(projectId, bqDataset, bqTable) {
  const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const bigquery = new BigQuery({ projectId: projectId });

  try {
    let results = await bigquery
      .dataset(bqDataset)
      .table(bqTable)
      .get();

    return results[1].schema.fields.length;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And in the second one

```
exports.cfTest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      result = await columnCount(
       'project','dataset','table'
      );
      console.log('sending response');
      res.send('<OUTPUT>' + result + '</OUTPUT>');
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send('<ERROR>' + err + '</ERROR>');     
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when deploying.  I don't think it likes the async keyword.  I tried adding "asyncawait": "1.0.7" to the package dependencies but it's still happening.  If I remove "async" it fails on the "await".
`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:33
exports.cfTest = async (req, res) => {
                       ^`

Comment: Which node.js version do you run your code ? Async/await is not a package, it is a language structure.

Comment: These are Google Cloud Functions i.e. Node 6.14.0

Comment: Ah I see Async/await works natively starting node 8.* LTS, if you can't upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I've checked the Google doc's again and found they're added 8.11.1 as a beta option.  it needed some SDK updates and deploy command changes but that did it.